# Macro only runs once excel vba before Runtime error 462: The remote server does not exist or is unavailble

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this code in vba which exports data from excel to access. This works fine running the first time and then running the second time "Runtime error 462: The remote server does not exist or is unavailable" shows up.

However if i was to restart excel, then it seems to works fine again the first time. I've tried googling solutions however most of them say set any objects to Nothing and empty variables and it still doesn't work.

```
Sub AccImport()
Dim acc As New Access.Application
Dim myValue As Variant
myValue = InputBox("Enter table name for access export")
acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\User 1\Documents\Database21.accdb"
acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        TableName:=myValue, _
        Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        Range:="Sheet2$A1:AL104"
        CurrentDb.TableDefs(myValue).Fields("F4").Properties!ColumnWidth = 2500
        CurrentDb.TableDefs(myValue).Fields("F7").Properties!ColumnWidth = 2500

acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
acc.Quit
Set acc = Nothing
myValue = Empty
MsgBox " The data has been exported"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
Range("A1").Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The below snippet of code is where this error seems to show up when running the second time round. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs(myValue).Fields("F4").Properties!ColumnWidth = 2500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone for a code tidy-up approach which should sort the problem.
Examinig each of the objects, from the code break line, in the Immediate Window would also help (e.g. what does "?Currentdb.Name" return)

1) VBA supports New as part of an object declaration, but... (best you research this bit. From memory it's always slower 'cause vba has to re-check if the object has been instantiated.)

```
Dim acc As Access.Application: Set acc = New Access.Application
```

2a) Qualify your calls to CurrentDb

```
acc.CurrentDb.TableDefs(myValue).Fields("F4").Properties!ColumnWidth = 2500
acc.CurrentDb.TableDefs(myValue).Fields("F7").Properties!ColumnWidth = 2500
```

2b) Even better, explicitly reference each of the objects in the tree [this will help with begugging]

```
' add Reference to "Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library"
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef

Set db = acc.CurrentDb
db.TableDefs.Refresh    ' CurrentDb should do this, but can't hurt
Set tdf = db.TableDefs(myValue)
With tdf
    .Fields("F4").Properties!ColumnWidth = 2500
    .Fields("F7").Properties!ColumnWidth = 2500
End With

Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

I hope that this helps,
GraemeR